# Simple code gets ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing `#A` code that prints `hello` if 1 is stored in spam, howdy if 2 is stored in spam and Greetings if anything else is stored.
see what I've written

```
while True:
    spam = int(input())
    if spam == 1:
        print('Hello')
    if spam == 2:
        print('Howdy')
    else:
        print('Greeting')
            break
```

Any time I type 2, I get Howdy and a blank space to type in some word figure, but once I hit enter, it gives this error

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

also, when I enter 1, it prints the whole instruction in the code.

Please how do i write this code

Comment: This is not valid Python code. Please fix your indentation of the break statement to reflect your original program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(input())` means take input and convert that input to `int` that means if you type any character other than integer (or **a blank space to type in some word figure**) you will get following error.

> invlaid literal for int() with base 10:

Also when you take 1 as an input first `Hello` will be printed then Greeting would be printed as you are not using `if..elif..else`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you help rewrite the code?

Comment: @JosephOnyemakonor You should study basic of python and then should understand how control flow works